# How to get Host name and port from CXF Message

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I tried to get hostname and port using

`Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
request.getRemoteAddr()`

but it is giving the client details.

How can we get the host name and port from cxf Message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the solution

`Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
String host = headers.get("host").get(0);`

This will get you the host ip with port.